# PHP switch always chooses last option

Tags: php, web, switch-statement

My PHP switch always chooses the last option. Even if I choose the the first option, my code will only execute the last option. How can I manage that it picks the option I choose?

Website:

[image: Website]

CODE:

```
<select name='auto-listings-package' id='auto-listings-package' class='auto-listings-package'>

                <?php foreach ( $packages as $package_id => $package ) : ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $package_id ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr( auto_listings_raw_price( $package['price'] ) ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $package['label'] ) ?></option>

                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['auto-listings-purchase'])) {
                            
                            if($package_id == '2823') {
                                wp_redirect('https://www.google.com');
                            } elseif ($package_id == '2633') {
                                wp_redirect('https://www.helemaaldebom.nl');
                            } else {
                                echo 'Something went wrong. Please contact our staff.';
                            }

                        }
                    ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select>
```

HTML

[image: HTML]

Comment: Why are you checking `if(isset($_POST['auto-listings-purchase']))` inside those cases? Don't you want to switch based on what value the user submitted via the select field of that name to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I'm checking that to execute that piece of code only when the submit button is triggered. As you can see the switch does look at what value the user submitted. 2823 & 2633 are the ID's of the packages they can choose. The if-statement for the submit-button is inside the case, it doesn't switch.

Comment: So other than checking whether a value was submitted via POST, you are not doing _anything_ right now with that value from your select field. I thought you wanted the switch decision made based on that value that was submitted via the form?

Comment: @CBroe I thought I was by switching between the ID's of the chosen packages. It's not working so I know I'm not doing it correctly, hence this post. Can you help me please?

Comment: I don't know what the point of looping over `$packages` is supposed to be here in the first place. You want the decision to be made based on the value the user submitted via the form? Well then switch on _that_. And if this code runs in a situation where you don't know yet, whether a value was actually submitted - then wrap the switch statement into `if(isset($_POST['auto-listings-purchase']))`, not the other way around.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! That was very helpful. I've changed the code but somehow it automatically chooses the last options (2633) but I've selected the first one (2823). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I forgot to fill the $package variable with the input of the user. I have put this before the if-statement and now it works.

```
$package_id = $_POST['auto-listings-package'];
```

Answer (score 0):

change the default to following

```
default:
                echo "-".$p.'- Something went wrong. Please contact our staff.';
```

and see the output.

that will help you to see why it does not match the condition (you might be getting spaces).

Comment: This only echo's an output but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: that will help you to see why it does not match the condition.

Comment: Well, the problem is that it'll take the last option before the default. So the switch doesn't reach the 'default'.

Comment: echo all the values before switch statement to see what you get. then you can find out what is wrong. if you are not getting your selected values that means your html post has a issue.